# Send TimePicker OnPropertyChanged event and Time Selected from Android Native To Shared Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get the TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener from the native Android to send to the shared project in Xamarin Form so that I can use the SelectedTime in the Xamarin shared project, but I'm not sure how to go about it, Here it what I have tried.
There is a problem with getting the TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener in the Android native project.
Original code from this git: repo: https://github.com/brminnick/24HourTimePicker

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;

using Java.Lang;

using TimePickerDemo;
using TimePickerDemo.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTimePicker24H), typeof(CustomTimePicker24HRenderer))]
namespace TimePickerDemo.Droid
{
    public class CustomTimePicker24HRenderer : ViewRenderer<TimePicker, Android.Widget.EditText>, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener, IJavaObject, IDisposable
    {
        TimePickerDialog _dialog;

        public CustomTimePicker24HRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        Context CurrentContext => Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
        IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

        public void OnTimeSet(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
        {
            var time = new TimeSpan(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
            Element.SetValue(TimePicker.TimeProperty, time);

            Control.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

            ClearFocus();
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            SetNativeControl(new Android.Widget.EditText(CurrentContext));

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Click += Control_Click;
                Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;

                if (Element != null && !Element.Time.Equals(default(TimeSpan)))
                    Control.Text = Element.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
                else
                    Control.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            }
        }

        void Control_FocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HasFocus)
            {
                ShowTimePicker();
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);
            }
            else
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
            }
        }

        void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => ShowTimePicker();

        void ShowTimePicker()
        {
            if (_dialog == null)
                _dialog = new TimePickerDialog(CurrentContext, this, Element.Time.Hours, Element.Time.Minutes, true);

           _dialog.OnTimeSetListener("TODO: Send TimePicker OnPropertyChanged event and Time Selected from here to Xamarin shared project");

            _dialog.UpdateTime(Element.Time.Hours, Element.Time.Minutes);

            _dialog.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
BackgroundColor="White" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:TimePickerDemo.CustomControls;assembly=TimePickerDemo" 
x:Class="TimePickerDemo.Views.TimePicker24HPage">  
    <ContentPage.Content>  
        <StackLayout Padding="30,80,30,0" Spacing="40" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">  
            <Label x:Name="LabelTimeText" Text="TimePicker 24H Format" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="20" />  
            <custom:CustomTimePicker24H TextColor="Gray" Format="HH:mm" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" /> </StackLayout>  
    </ContentPage.Content>  
</ContentPage>
```

Shared CodeBehind in Xamarin Forms

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using Xamarin.Forms;  
namespace TimePickerDemo.Views {  
    public partial class TimePicker24HPage: ContentPage {  
        public TimePicker24HPage() {  
            InitializeComponent();  
        }
    
    //From Android native  
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {         
           if(propertyName == "SelectedTime")
            {
              LabelTimeText.Text = Time;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

CustomControls

```
namespace TimePickerDemo
{
    public class CustomTimePicker24H : TimePicker
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do? Do you want to notify the shared project about a change? What is supposed to happen? If you want to send an information to the shared project, there are several ways to do this. You can create an interface and a platform-specific implementation and use the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) or another IoC container to resolve it. You can also use the MessagingCenter to send a simple notification.

Comment: Please show the code from the (shared) Xamarin.Forms project where want to use the value.

Comment: @Julian actually what I would like is to Send the OnPropertyChanged event and Time Selected from Android Native project to the Xamarin shared project

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged()` is a method and it doesn't belong to the renderer. You probably mean the `PropertyChanged` event. Every observable object needs to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface in order to notify subscribers about a change. You cannot simply invoke the event for other classes. [TimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/timepicker) already exposes an observable property: `Time`. **Please show your XAML and code-behind.**

Comment: @Julian I have added the shared code, where I need to use an if else statement in the  OnPropertyChanged event to get the selected time from the Android into the LabelTimeText in the XAML

Answer (score 1):

First of all, give your *CustomTimePicker24H* instance an `x:Name`:

```xml
<custom:CustomTimePicker24H
    x:Name="MyTimePicker"
    Format="HH:mm" />
```

Now, you have two options.

## Option 1: Use data binding

Simply bind the `Text` property of the label to the `Time` property of `MyTimePicker`:

```xml
<Label
    x:Name="LabelTimeText"
    Text="{Binding Time, Source={x:Reference MyTimePicker}}" />
```

Additionally, you can specify an optional `StringFormat` for the label in the binding expression to customize the format of the displayed value:

```xml
<Label
    x:Name="LabelTimeText"
    Text="{Binding Time, Source={x:Reference MyTimePicker}, StringFormat='{0:HH:mm}'}" />
```

## Option 2: Use an event handler

You can access the `MyTimePicker` via the code-behind of your page to add an event handler and then set the `Text` property of the label in the event handler:

```cs
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TimePickerDemo.Views
{  
    public partial class TimePicker24HPage: ContentPage
    {  
        public TimePicker24HPage()
        {  
            InitializeComponent();

            MyTimePicker.PropertyChanged += OnTimePickerPropertyChanged;
        }
    
        private void OnTimePickerPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if(args.PropertyName == nameof(MyTimePicker.Time))
            {
                // do something here
                LabelTimeText.Text = MyTimePicker.Time.ToString("HH:mm");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Notes

These are two common ways of solving this type of problem. Your control, which derives from Xamarin.Form's [TimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.timepicker), already exposes an observable and bindable property called [Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.timepicker.time?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-timepicker-time), so you don't need to send another notification from within the custom renderer. You can get rid of the `_dialog.OnTimeSetListener()`, it's not required. Using the Android listener approach would make the code more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @ Julian, thanks for this. Sorry I missed adding the CustomControl before, I have  now added the CustomControl class: public class CustomTimePicker24H : TimePicker{ }. Not sure if you will need to update your code to account for the CustomControl.

Comment: No, I inferred that already from the context. My answer still stands. Did you try the two options? I'd go with Option 1 if you just need to display the selected value.

Comment: Thanks @Julian option 2 is more suited for for my shared code and it worked fine.

Comment: @CodingSoft Great, I'm glad I could help. Please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @ Julian, but how about if I wanted to use the Android listener approach, please can you share the code for this also.

Comment: Why would you want that? That adds complexity and you gain nothing from it.

Comment: @ Julian, good question, it's just that once I know there is an option available I always like to have it in my tool box as there might be a need to use that option.

Comment: I see. In that case, you may want to read about dependency injection and inversion of control and read about the Android APIs. It's too much to explain all options here.

Comment: It will really be nice to get it done also with the 3rd option using the Android listener approach. I'll keep researching on the Android APIs to find the solution.

Comment: I showed you the most common Xamarin.Forms ways of doing it. Using the listener approach, you'll bypass the idea of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and add more complexity for a problem that has already been solved for you. I understand that you're eager to learn the different aspects of XF, but you won't gain anything useful from it. IMHO, you'd be better off learning about Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection rather than getting deep into an unimportant detail of an Android-specific API. Do as you see fit.

Comment: @ Julian, I do appreciate the solution you gave, but I have seen the _dialog.OnDateSetListener() used in a project before hence the reason I would really like to use _dialog.OnTimeSetListener() option too. I'm okay with DI/IOC but using the _dialog.OnTimeSetListener() from Android native is what I'm new to.